# facebook application designing?

Tags: facebook, fbml

im creating an facebook application that gets uploaded pictures in albums. no display design.

i want to display the pictures in my facebook application like album pics in facebook.

im using php..(how to design the facebook application to view multiple photos, form)

Comment: Ok. So what is your question?

Comment: Please provide more information on what technology you are using?

Comment: facebook image display with design border, frame like that.. in php

Answer (score 1):

yes that can be done.

Comment: <fb:photo pid="<?php echo $photo_detail['pid'] ?>" size="thumb" /> 
how it can be done, this is fbml how to set border, frame